# XNA smooth animation at high speed for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, xna, sprite

My 2d game has a sprite which is moving from top to bottom (travelling Y +ve direction),  its smooth enough in 30 fps, as sprite's Y position adding 1 pixel in each frame (Y= Y+1px).
Now the problem is when i want move the sprite in high speed, that is Y = Y + 10px, the motion looks no smooth at all since adding 10px in each frame.
Would like to know, is there anyway i can acheive high speed with smooth animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XNA performance on WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687009/xna-performance-on-wp7)

Comment: @Arkain  No Sir, i dont want to change the FPS speed rate but animation.

Comment: and it's not smooth because you have to move it 10 pixels pr. frame right? so increasing the frame rate will make it render more often, and make it smoother, what am I missing?

Comment: @Arkain my game animation is moving based on pixel, so wanted to know this is the way to do it? or some alternate solution... but i understood. thanks.

Comment: the best way is to make the animation be dependent on time instead of fps, but increasing the refresh rate will make it seem smoother in any case, because you don't have to move the sprite as many pixels per frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use frame based movement, if your game has a "hickup" suddenly your player, enemies etc. are not moving "realistically" but are slowed just because of your device. I advise you to use time based movement.

Currently I guess you have something like this:

```
Update(GameTime aTime)
{
    mPlayer.Position += mPlayer.Direction;
}
```

Now consider what happens if your game is running at 10FPS, 100FPS or 0 FPS. The movement is not consistent and thus not fluid. If you change that, so movement is based on the elapsed time instead, you get a much more consistent animation, something like:

```
Update(GameTime aTime)
{
    mPlayer.Position += aTime.Milliseconds * (Constants.PlayerWalkSpeed * mPlayer.Direction);
}
```

And finally if that isn't smooth enough you need to fake it, like adding motion blur, which is quite easy to do in 2D. Just store the last couple of old positions and draw the player sprite at these position with less alpha than the current one.